# Best way to send data from PC to Android

Tags: android, arduino

What is the best way to send small strings through the Internet from a PC to an Android and from an Android to a PC?

I have an Arduino which reads temperature values from two sensors and send them to a [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) application. I would like to create an Android application that read these values through the Internet and show them in the screen of my smartphone. Is there any guide to send small strings through [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or something like that? I want a very simple guide. As simple as possible, because I am a beginner.

Comment: how would you like to develop your android app? a lot depends on that!

Comment: what do you mean? I want to develop a java android app with eclipse

Comment: So why is your question tagged php and not java?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) to send your data from the computer to a web server using [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29):

```
import urllib2, urllib
mydata = [('one','1')]    #The first is the var name the second is the value
mydata = urllib.urlencode(mydata)
path = 'http://localhost/new.php'    #The URL you want to POST to
req = urllib2.Request(path, mydata)
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print page
```

Write them to a file on the server using [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP):

```
<?php
    $file = "path/to/file/here" ;
    file_put_contents($file, $_POST['one'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Now develop your Android app which reads the values from the file. Use append or whatever if you need to save all the data or if you want data to be replaced.

Otherwise, you could just use a [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) connection to send serial data between your devices. See *[Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)* (on ANdroid Developers).

You might also be interested in *[Simple Android and Java Bluetooth Application](http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/)* and in *[Data transfer between Android and Arduino via Bluetooth](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php)*.

Comment: anyway your question is pretty wide so I can only give you an idea of what you could do using the scripting you mentioned.

Comment: nice idea but will it be appropriate to be run every 5 sec?

Comment: why not? I use a similar system to update two database one local and one on a server, every 2 sec... it works smoothly ;)
as long as it's just a small string